# set image properties based on id in css file

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure:

```
<div id="bookshelf">
        <img src="images/bookshelf.png" id="background_img" />
        <img src="images/book-cover-people.png"/>
        <img src="images/sports_cover.png" />
        <img src="images/travels_book_cover.png" />
        <img src="images/photoalbum_cover.png"/>
    </div>
```

and i want to set css properties differently for each image. how can i specify in the css file that for one image i want certain properties and for another image i want others.

currently what i am doing is:

```
#bookshelf img {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

but this is changing the properties of every image inside the bookshelf div, not specific images.

Comment: You could do it with classes, IDs, index, src... what ever you want. Have you tried anything?#

Comment: i dont know how to set it in the css. in this case i tried with #bookshelf img that is setting every img inside div i want to be able to put there the image id so it only affects it.

Comment: Well.. you could give each image an ID and use that in your CSS. Like `#background_img { ... }`

Comment: it worked. css has so many different possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use an `id` attribute on each image, unique to each `img` element.

Take:

```
<div id="bookshelf">
    <img src="images/bookshelf.png" id="background_img" id="one" />
    <img src="images/book-cover-people.png" id="two"/>
    <img src="images/sports_cover.png" id="three" />
    <img src="images/travels_book_cover.png" id="four" />
    <img src="images/photoalbum_cover.png" id="five"/>
</div>
```

now you can use the following selector to set properties that are common to all the images:

```
#bookshelf img {}
```

and the following selectors for styles applicable to individual images:

```
#one { }
#two { }
#three { }
#four { }
#five { }
```

Comment: It is a bit unnecessary to have 2 IDs in the selector. `img#one` would do instead of `#bookshelf img#one`

Comment: even just #one would have the same effect, unless there was another element onbthye page with the same id

Comment: @SamDenton yes you are right, no need for the `img` because there can be only one `#one` on the page. IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Another element on the **same page** with the **same ID** would be invalid.

Comment: sorry, was thinking abbout class, since thats all i realy use

Comment: I have made adjustments for selector efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="bookshelf">
    <img src="images/bookshelf.png" id="imageOne" />
    <img src="images/book-cover-people.png" id="imageTwo" />
    <img src="images/sports_cover.png" id="imageThree" />
    <img src="images/travels_book_cover.png" id="imageFour" />
    <img src="images/photoalbum_cover.png" id="imageFive" />
</div>

<style>
#bookshelf #imageOne{}
#bookshelf #imageTwo{}
#bookshelf #imageThree{}
#bookshelf #imageFour{}
#bookshelf #imageFive{}
</style>

You can do this way too.
```

Comment: That's an inappropriate use of class, unless there are to be other groups of images that need the same styling. ID attributes would be the correct and efficient way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @michaelward82 Yes. after 7years I saw my own answer and I laughed. I was newbie that time when I posted this answer. I agree id attributes would be correct approach to achieve the goal. I edited this answer now.